# var_dump on json result produces output int(1)

Tags: php, json

This is the result which comes

```
{"response":1, "num":"322343434", "id":22, "again":0, "text":"xe", "branchId":0};
```

code

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo('<br><br>');
var_dump(json_decode($result));
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

Output `int(1) int(1)`

I am just trying to format the result with the properties I need name and id  which I would echo out.

Comment: With provided json code is correct - https://3v4l.org/3W5WR. `var_dump($result)` also.

Comment: Curl will return true (or `1`) because you forgot to `include curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`, which will return the result as a string that can be assigned to your variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get curl to return a string you need to include: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

Curl is returning TRUE (or `1` in this case), which is the expected result when you do not explicitly instruct it to return the result as a string.

This line needs to be added after `curl_init()` and before `curl_exec()`.